# And condition usage on grep command

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have two regular expression, and trying to bind it into And condition

what I got

```
-grep -E "/[1-9]{4,}/" file
-grep -E '([0-9])(.*\1){3}' file
```

I tried to take a regular expression from each command, then bind it with multiple grep with pipe

```
cat file | grep pattern1 | grep patterns
```

, but didn't work.

anyone can teach me way to use and condition for grep with these two patterns?

```
"/[1-9]{4,}/"   '([0-9])(.*\1){3}'
```

sample input

```
Q4HXD/7100525/+wg4C54V2I4mh4Xh
aaaa/123/422444qjem,,qewriiafa
!#@AVADFQWERASDFASDFQervzxcilh
```

expected output

Q4HXDa **/7100525/**+wg**4**C5**4**V2I**4**mh**4**Xh

which satisfy both condition

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `grep -P '^(?=.*[1-9]{4}).*([0-9])(.*\1){3}' file`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew isn't it for or condition?

Comment: What happens if you only try the first regex on your input file? There should be no output, as no lines match.

Your first solution:
`cat file | grep pattern1 | grep pattern2`  should work.

Comment: OR is `/[1-9]{4,}/|([0-9])(.*\1){3}`. AND is `grep -P '^(?=.*/[1-9]{4}/).*([0-9])(.*\1){3}' file`

Comment: @noam first regex will only find number enclosed by /, second will find number that repeated more than 4 times in one line.

Comment: @noam ah think I made some mistake with first regex  original command for the first regex was grep -E "/[1-9]{4,}/" file

Comment: So, you just forgot to add `-E`? `cat file | grep -E $pattern1 | grep -E $patterns`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't think so, when I do -grep -E "/[1-9]{4,}/" file it shows up expected result, but when it used with other pattern or cat command it doesn't work did I made any mistake while using that regex?

Comment: I think your main issue is `[1-9]`, you need to match any digit, `[0-9]`. See https://ideone.com/AHbi2B

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thx for pointing it out, just fixed it, I tried your commend. The expected result should be  attern1 ∩attern2 ,  but output from that commend was something like  attern1 U attern2.

Comment: Then consider fixing the sample input/expected output in the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah I made mistake while type your answer into putty. commend from the link was correct.  thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` to match any digit in a POSIX pattern and make sure both patterns are handled as POSIX ERE by passing `-E` option:

```
cat file | grep -E '/[0-9]{4,}/' | grep -E '([0-9])(.*\1){3}'
```

Else, you may use a PCRE pattern like

```
grep -P '^(?=.*/[0-9]{4,}/).*([0-9])(.*\1){3}' file
```

See an [online grep demo](https://ideone.com/AHbi2B)

The latter pattern matches

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?=.*/[0-9]{4,}/)` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there is `/`, 4 or more digits, `/` after any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `([0-9])` - Group 1: any digit
- `(.*\1){3}` - three occurrences of any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, and then the Group 1 value.